# why does jquery first child work in ie6?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

why does jquery first child work in ie6 and :first-child not?
Is there some hack or so.

```
:first-child
```

vs

```
$(":first-child")
```

Comment: @Michal "why does jquery first child work in ie6 and :first-child not?"

Comment: I see, `:first child` is meant as CSS selector?

Comment: Why are you still using IE6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean the CSS selector `:first-child` vs jQuery selector `:first-child`:
this is because jquery has it's own javascript implementation and css is browser dependant...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses it's own parser not the one in the browser

Answer (score 1):

jQuery would implement that functionality. In fact it would implement all selectors because IE6 doesn't support querySelectorAll()